# 2 Image Inputs - Display both images - Fiddl

Tags: jquery, html, image, input, replace

first of all: NICE COMMUNITY, i learned so much in the past few days.

I've got a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/1dgaudxo/

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#full-sized-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function(){
    readURL(this);
});
```

I have 2 Images, which you can replace by clicking on them and select a own picture.

The first one works, you click on it then the windows opens to select a new one, but the secon input doesn't work..

Does someone have an idea ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a minute to compare this fiddle with your, there is a coulple of missing handler and wrong selector, now work as expected

**http://jsfiddle.net/InferOn/drwm84ce/8/**

**HTML**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" name="images[]" class="uploads" size="chars" />
    <div id="full-sized-image">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/My_personal_black_cat.gif" alt="Audi" id="full-sized-img" />
    </div>
    <input type='file' id="imgInp2" name="images[]" class="uploads" size="chars" />
    <div id="overlay_image">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Farm-Fresh_cat.png" alt="Audi advert" id="overlay_img" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$('#full-sized-image').click(function () {
    $('#imgInp').click();
});
$('#overlay_image').click(function () {
    $('#imgInp2').click();
});

function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#full-sized-img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

function readURL2(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#overlay_img').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
});
$("#imgInp2").change(function () {
    readURL2(this);
});
```